# ASP.Net Web Application doesn't work - IIS7 configuration or install issue?

Tags: windows-7, iis-7, configuration, asp.net, installation

Obligatory background information: I'm a developer and I recently got a new workstation.  My attempts to get my companies' main web application working have utterly failed.  I have gone through all of the steps necessary to configure it and get it working in IIS-7 (except it isn't working).

Facts of note:

It is a .net 3.5 web application, and forms authentication is enabled.  I am using the Classic .Net AppPool.  The website's path is valid (it's set up as an application under the Default Website).  The Classic .Net App Pool user/account has RX,W permissions on the entire folder structure and it's contents.

I can browse to the application without issue, however it's obvious something is screwed up.  I can log in however; we're using the AspMembershipProvider so I think ASP.net is working ok but I can't rule out a problem here.

When we get to the main screen, here's what we see:

[image]

Naturally, this is not what our website is supposed to look like.

The top image is our logo.  The path to the logo is valid.  Viewing the results of this in Fiddler, I show that this image - and several others on the page - has a Content-Length of 0.  All of the results in fiddler are 200s; no errors are shown.  The buttons are all javascript (Dojo in fact), but everything there is configured properly.  All stylesheets exist where they're supposed to be.  The paths all look valid.

Does anyone have any idea what the problem is here?  I'm at a loss here.  Top people at MyCompany (Top. People.) are also at a loss.

Comment: Do the files on your server exist and actually contain data?

Comment: Yes.  In usual fashion, we discovered the answer after I asked the question!

Answer (score 1):

It turns out Static Content was not installed (under World Wide Web Services\Common HTTP Features).  That fixed it.

Comment: Static content is a crutch for lazy web developers who want their site to work. Get your DevOPS on and eliminate static content from your site.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use static content? Dynamically serving images that are static makes no sense to me. And would negatively impact optimizing the site via caching mechanisms.